# How to handle $basesearch in a Nexus Proxy Repo

Tags: linux, nexus, yum, dnf

We are using Oracle Linux 9 and are introducing Nexus as a local proxy repo for the yum/dnf repos.  Idea is to proxy those we need then combine them to a single group repo that we use from the servers.

When creating the proxy repos, how should I handle the variables.  For example, the default repo definition for the Oracle AppStream Repo specifies the URL as

```
baseurl=https://yum$ociregion.$ocidomain/repo/OracleLinux/OL9/appstream/$basearch/
```

When defining my proxy repo, should I substitute values for the variables or not?  I.e. should I point my proxy at a source of `http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL9/appstream/x86_64` or just `http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL9/appstream/` ?

I was thinking that if I do the first I would then not include the `$basearch` in the definition for my Nexus group repo but in the latter case I should - is that correct?  Is there an advantage to or the other?

Using the Open Source version of Nexus.